# How to minimize distortion in time series visualization of commodity prices?

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

I'm building a product that has amongst other features a visualization of commodity prices for a set of futures contracts.

The problem I'm having is we're using a pretty naive technique to visualize this time series, we simply take max and min values of the time period considered and add a 20% on top and bottom to train the Y scale.

The result of doing this is changes of 0.01 can look identical to changes of 1 at first when changing time periods.

Is there a better way to do this without making the charts unreadable?

Comment: The answer may depend on the program you are using. For instance in R's `ggplot` package there is a function called `coord_cartesian` that allows me to zoom in on a section of a graph without changing the scaling. Using this approach I could create y axis limits like you describe above (adding/subtracting some reasonable constant from local max/mins) for any section of time (specifying x axis limits based on the period of interest).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider: find the max/min across all past time periods. Add a button to allow zooming in on a give time period that re-scales to the structure you currently have . This way when zoomed out the time periods all have the same scaling